# How to close a record page opened in a separate lightning tab in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

There should be a delete button (quick action) on the record page. Since after deleting this record, a redirect to a certain tab should occur, I can't use standard button, I use quick action is done using LWC. And everything works fine, but after the redirect, lightning tab , where the record is open, it does not close and the name of the record is indicated there. And if you switch to it, you will get a message like: The requested resource does not exist.

How can I close this tab with deleted record before/after redirection in LWC?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using console. Solution should be to wrap LWC/Quick Action in aura component and fire an event on delete. Leverage workspace API to get the event and close tab.

Comment: Let's have more details. What is the workspace API, what event are we talking about and how to get it? And I'm catching it in an aura wrapper, right?